# Can you develop web apps for Apple TV?

Tags: ios, apple-tv

I am new to app development, and I know we can develop apps for iPhone and iPad.

However, I am not sure if I can develop a web app for Apple TV. Can you develop web apps for Apple TV? If so, where can I go to learn about this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no web browser on the Apple TV, so you can't currently develop web applications for a non-jailbroken device. Same goes for native applications.

Jailbroken Apple TVs are another story, but it sounds like that isn't your target here.

Comment: Yes that is correct, I just wanted to know what was officially supported. Is it possible to develop non web based apps for apple TV?

Comment: @developer - Currently, no, unless you are dealing with jailbroken devices.

Comment: ok. Thanks @Brad Larson. I appreciate your response.

Comment: You are wrong, the device doesn't need to be jailbroken, you can use the webview using classFromString or doing modifications on Xcode. BTW,  the question is a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32503582/web-app-in-tvos/

Answer (score 1):

UIWebView doesn't exist in TV OS. 
Here is list from [Apple's tvOS Developer Library document](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/tvos/releasenotes/General/tvOS90APIDiffs/index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40016577)

> tvOS Developer Library — PrereleaseDeveloperSearch iOS 9.1 to tvOS 9 API Diffs iOS 9.1 to tvOS 9.0 API Diffs
>
> **JavaScript**
>
> TVMLJS (Added)
>
> **Objective-C**
>
> /usr/include Accounts (Removed) 
>   AddressBook (Removed) 
>   AddressBookUI
>   (Removed) AssetsLibrary (Removed) AudioToolbox AVFoundation AVKit
>   CloudKit Contacts (Removed) ContactsUI (Removed) CoreAudioKit
>   (Removed) CoreBluetooth CoreData CoreLocation CoreMIDI (Removed)
>   CoreMotion (Removed) CoreSpotlight CoreTelephony (Removed) EventKit
>   (Removed) EventKitUI (Removed) ExternalAccessory (Removed)
>   GameController GameKit GSS (Removed) HealthKit (Removed) HomeKit
>   (Removed) iAd (Removed) LocalAuthentication (Removed) MapKit (Removed)
>   MediaPlayer MessageUI (Removed) Metal MultipeerConnectivity (Removed)
>   NetworkExtension (Removed) NewsstandKit (Removed) NotificationCenter
>   (Removed) PassKit (Removed) Photos (Removed) PhotosUI (Removed)
>   PushKit (Removed) QuickLook (Removed) ReplayKit (Removed)
>   SafariServices (Removed) Social (Removed) StoreKit TVMLKit (Added)
>   TVServices (Added) Twitter (Removed) UIKit VideoToolbox (Removed)
>   WatchConnectivity (Removed) WatchKit (Removed) WebKit (Removed)
>
> **Swift**
>
> Accelerate Accounts (Removed) AddressBook (Removed) AddressBookUI
>   (Removed) AssetsLibrary (Removed) AudioToolbox AudioUnit AVFoundation
>   AVKit CloudKit Contacts (Removed) ContactsUI (Removed) CoreAudioKit
>   (Removed) CoreBluetooth CoreData CoreFoundation CoreGraphics
>   CoreLocation CoreMIDI (Removed) CoreMotion (Removed) CoreSpotlight
>   CoreTelephony (Removed) Darwin EventKit (Removed) EventKitUI (Removed)
>   ExternalAccessory (Removed) Foundation GameController GameKit GSS
>   (Removed) HealthKit (Removed) HomeKit (Removed) iAd (Removed)
>   LocalAuthentication (Removed) MachO MapKit (Removed) MediaPlayer
>   MessageUI (Removed) Metal MultipeerConnectivity (Removed)
>   NetworkExtension (Removed) NewsstandKit (Removed) NotificationCenter
>   (Removed) ObjectiveC PassKit (Removed) Photos (Removed) PhotosUI
>   (Removed) PushKit (Removed) QuickLook (Removed) ReplayKit (Removed)
>   SafariServices (Removed) simd Social (Removed) StoreKit Swift TVMLKit
>   (Added) TVServices (Added) Twitter (Removed) UIKit VideoToolbox
>   (Removed) WatchConnectivity (Removed) WatchKit (Removed) WebKit
>   (Removed)

If you want to have anything closer to web development, check TVML which is easier for a web developer to work for TV app using a kind of Apple's own markup language.

Comment: We tend to frown on link only answers, as over time the links may get broken. Please block qoute at least the pertinent information of both links, so this answer is still useful if the links do break.