# UIWebView is unavailable: not available on tvOS

Tags: uiwebview, apple-tv, tvos

Is there anyway to use a `UIWebView` with an application targeted for [tvos](/questions/tagged/tvos)?
This Apple Doc, [UIWebView Class Reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/tvos/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIWebView_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/c/tdef/UIWebViewNavigationType), would suggest otherwise would it not? Or am I just interpreting this all wrong?

> `UIWebViewNavigationType` (New in tvos 9.0)

Comment: UIWebView / Webkit is not available in tvOS.

Comment: @JessBowers what would you suggest for the *hard* way?

Comment: deleted that qualifier. I would suggest making an app with UIKit

Comment: or rather, UIKit only. There isn't a way to use WebViews to render content on tvOS

Comment: possible duplicate of [Web app in tvOS](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32503582/web-app-in-tvos)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`UIWebView` is not available for tvOS, as @JessBowers mentioned in the comments, and is documented here: [UIKit Changes for Objective-C](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/tvos/releasenotes/General/tvOS90APIDiffs/Objective-C/UIKit.html), [UIKit Changes for Swift](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/tvos/releasenotes/General/tvOS90APIDiffs/Swift/UIKit.html).

For a complete list of iOS API's that are available for tvOS refer to: [iOS 9.0 to tvOS 9.0 API Differences](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/content/releasenotes/General/tvOS10APIDiffs/index.html)

Answer (score 1):

Although WebKit/UIWebView is not officially available in tvOS, some people have figured out that it is possible to use that functionality if you are willing to edit your system header files. No word on whether Apple would actually approve a tvOS app that is using such an undocumented API.

- http://www.macrumors.com/2015/11/06/apple-tv-4-web-browser-tvos-hack/
- https://github.com/steventroughtonsmith/tvOSBrowser