# What is the User Agent string for Apple TVs running tvOS?

Tags: apple-tv, tvos

What is the User Agent string for Apple TVs running the new Apple tvOS operating system (which I believe is based on iOS)? Do they report themselves as being "iOS" devices?

Comment: What are you trying to do?  An app that makes an HTTP request can set whatever value it wants as its User-Agent header.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Apple TV does not support the WebKit framework, meaning you can't technically show webpages and therefore have a User Agent.

However, if you somehow had it running one the new TVOS, the User Agent would definitely be :

> Mozilla/5.0 (Apple TV; CPU iPhone OS 9_0 like Mac OS X)
>   AppleWebKit/601.1.46 (KHTML, like Gecko) Mobile/13T534YI

Answer (score 2):

I didn't see any official documentation on this, but a number of people have reported the user agent for tvOS being something a long the lines of:

- `[AppName]/1 CFNetwork/758.1.6 Darwin/15.0.0`
- `[AppName]/1 CFNetwork/758.1.2 Darwin/15.0.0`

I have seen something similar. 
Here is mine:

- `[AppName]/1 CFNetwork/758.2.8 Darwin/15.2.0`
  **Note:** These User Agents can change.

You can check for yourself using a HTTP proxy and monitor, such as [Charles](http://www.macupdate.com/app/mac/12462/charles).
Also mentioned here on [SO](https://superuser.com/questions/42813/looking-for-http-debugging-proxy-for-mac-similar-to-fiddler-on-windows).

Sources:

- [StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33701867/change-user-agent-for-xmlhttprequest-in-tvml-app)
- [Apple Dev Forums](https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/21983)
- [Apple Dev Forums](https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/19681)

Answer (score 2):

tvOS does not currently (as of October, 2017) expose any web view components (such as `UIWebView`) in its SDK. However, you can still force tvOS to load `UIWebView` using reflection (see answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32715013/633347)), and then extract user agent string from it.

```
let webViewClass: AnyObject.Type = NSClassFromString("UIWebView")!
let webViewObject: NSObject.Type = webViewClass as! NSObject.Type
let webView: AnyObject = webViewObject.init()
let userAgent = webView.stringByEvaluatingJavaScript(from: "navigator.userAgent")
print(userAgent!)
```

Output:

```
Mozilla/5.0 (iPhone; CPU iPhone OS 11_0 like Mac OS X) AppleWebKit/604.1.38 (KHTML, like Gecko) Mobile/15J380
```

Comment: This solution works, but the output is describing it as iPhone instead of AppleTV