# Change User-Agent for XMLHttpRequest in TVML app

Tags: tvos, apple-tv, tvjs

I'm working on an Apple TV app using TVMLKit. My app's JavaScript code tries to send an HTTP request to a server using `XMLHttpRequest`. The server is expecting a specific user agent, so I tried this:

```
var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
request.open("GET", url, true);
request.setRequestHeader("User-Agent", "MyApp");
request.send();
```

The server receives a different User-Agent header:

```
User-Agent: <Projectname>/1 CFNetwork/758.1.6 Darwin/15.0.0
```

If I change the header name to something different, it shows up in the request headers. I guess Apple is replacing the User-Agent field right before sending the request. Is there a way to prevent this?

Comment: Hit same problem yesterday. It seems that Apple uses browser's implementation and setting some headers as `User-Agent` are prohibited.

Answer (score 0):

After spending two days on investigating this question I've came to solution with creating native `GET` and `POST` methods in swift end exposing them to javascript. This isn't best solution but still I want to share it. Maybe it could help someone.

Here how it works

First we need to install [Alamofire](https://github.com/Alamofire/Alamofire) library. We will use it for creating requests.

> Readme on github has all instructions you need to install it

After installing Alamofire we need to import it in `AppDelegate.swift`

```cpp
import Alamofire
```

Then we need to create function in app controller (`AppDelegate.swift`) that will expose methods to javascript

```cpp
func appController(appController: TVApplicationController, evaluateAppJavaScriptInContext jsContext: JSContext)
{
    let requests = [String : AnyObject]()

    let get: @convention(block) (String, String, [String : String]?) -> Void = { (cId:String, url:String, headers:[String : String]?) in

        Alamofire.request(.GET, url, headers: headers)
            .responseString { response in
                jsContext.evaluateScript("requests." + cId + "(" + response.result.value! + ")")
        }
    }

    let post: @convention(block) (String, String, [String : AnyObject]?, [String : String]?) -> Void = { (cId:String, url:String, parameters:[String : AnyObject]?, headers:[String : String]?) in

        Alamofire.request(.POST, url, parameters: parameters, headers: headers)
            .responseString { response in
                jsContext.evaluateScript("requests." + cId + "(" + response.result.value! + ")")
        }
    }

    jsContext.setObject(requests, forKeyedSubscript: "requests");
    jsContext.setObject(unsafeBitCast(get, AnyObject.self), forKeyedSubscript: "nativeGET");
    jsContext.setObject(unsafeBitCast(post, AnyObject.self), forKeyedSubscript: "nativePOST");
}
```

> Full code of `AppDelegate.swift` you can find [here](https://github.com/a-ignatov-parc/tvos-soap4.me/blob/f0ae4e25b1aa8748cd4c426f9d8fdacf60fa7d10/tvos/soap4.me/AppDelegate.swift#L120-L143)

All set! Now we have access to `nativeGET` and `nativePOST` functions from javascript.

The last thing is to make requests and retrieve responses. I haven't understand how to make callback executions in swift so I've used `jsonp` approach using runtime generated functions and passing their names to native functions.

Here how it looks in javascript

```js
export function get(url, headers = {}) {
    return new Promise((resolve) => {
        const cId = `get${Date.now()}`;
        requests[cId] = response => {
            delete requests[cId];
            resolve(response);
        }
        nativeGET(cId, url, headers);
    });
}

export function post(url, parameters = {}, headers = {}) {
    return new Promise((resolve) => {
        const cId = `post${Date.now()}`;
        requests[cId] = response => {
            delete requests[cId];
            resolve(response);
        }
        nativePOST(cId, url, parameters, headers);
    });
}
```

> The code above is written in ES6 and you'll need to include `Promise` polifill in your TVJS app.

Now we can make `GET` and `POST` requests applying any header we need

```js
post('http://example.com/', {
    login: 'xxx', 
    password: 'yyy'
}, {
    'User-Agent': 'My custom User-Agent'
})
```