# Show content 's website in TVOS app

Tags: uiwebview, tvos

I want to show content of a website: [www.google.com](http://www.google.com) in my TVOS app, but TVOS don't support UIWebView (In the first ViewController(MainScreen), I have a view, and I want to show web content at here)
I haven't any idea.Please help me.

Edit: I try with post : [Web app in tvOS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32503582/web-app-in-tvos) but it will be rejected by apple if I use UIWebView

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Web app in tvOS](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32503582/web-app-in-tvos)

Comment: you can not use UIWebView or Safari view Controller in TVOS they are prohabited, so have a look on TVML

Answer (score 0):

Accessing dynamic web content is strictly prohibited in tvOS for the foreseeable future. Even if you find a way to hack around the restriction, the likelihood of the app being accepted into the tvOS App Store is nil.

There are a number of reasons Apple is making this stance, specifically:

• Apple can better control the quality experience of apps if they know exactly what content is going to be displayed

• Limit potential web exploits (phishing, viruses, etc.)

• Force developers to support native features and layouts

Though it appears like this may change in the future (see: https://twitter.com/ryanolsonk/status/642069462452056064).

Additional reading material on the subject: http://thenextweb.com/apple/2015/09/14/apples-made-it-difficult-to-build-tvos-apps-and-thats-good-for-users/