# UIWebView and UIWebViewDelegate in tvOS

Tags: uiwebview, tvos

I understand that it is currently prohibited to use `UIWebView` for App Store apps. However, I've seen from [jcesarmobile](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1351469/jcesarmobile)'s [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32715013/6102322) that it is possible to still use it. Based on this method, is there a way to also use `UIWebViewDelegate` or another way to detect if the `UIWebView` has loaded or is still loading?

Comment: why would you use it, if your app is going to be rejected?

Comment: @EugeneZhenyaGordin we're not submitting the app to the store we're currently using it as an internal tool