# Create a Apple TV App using existing web application

Tags: swift, tvos, apple-tv, tvml

Since Web Kit cant be used to distribute Apple TV application, I was searching through alternate ways to display web content in Apple TV app. Using TVML I could play video source from a web site from Apple TV app. 
My doubt is that can I display a web site by providing the link as like the UIWebView does!

I have already a developed web site with me and need to have a TV app version also. Is it possible ?

The following code works for me, and it loaded a video from a URL.

```html
var player = new Player();
var playlist = new Playlist();
var mediaItem = new MediaItem("video", videoURL);
player.playlist = playlist;
player.playlist.push(mediaItem);
player.present();
```

Comment: For anyone googling here, the simple answer is **no**, it's impossible to play a web page or a web view, on AppleTV.  You have to custom make one of the "TVML" AppleTV apps.

Answer (score 1):

If your plan is to load your existing website into a `WebView` you can take a look at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32503582/web-app-in-tvos). Even if you manage to load it, I doubt Apple will let you publish it.

If your existing web application serves parse-able data like JSON you can use it to bulid a TVML app.

As a reference you can check Apple's sample applications:

- [TVML Guide: Core concepts in TVML and TVMLKit](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/samplecode/TVMLGuide/Introduction/Intro.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40016778)
- [TVML Catalog: Using TVML Templates](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/samplecode/TVMLCatalog/Introduction/Intro.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40016505)
- [TVMLAudioVideo: Audio and Video Playback on tvOS](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/samplecode/TVMLAudioVideo/Introduction/Intro.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40016506)

What you could also do, despite **I would not recommend it** is to modify your existing web application to serve TVML templates

Answer (score 1):

one way to do it might be with your server, you can let it serve down a tvml version of the site (maybe). But the underline thing is: it won't magically work, it requires work to be done.

Here are some reference you might found helpful

https://github.com/emadalam/atvjs

https://github.com/ramitos/react-tvml