# How to access to the file UIWebView.h?

Tags: objective-c, xamarin.ios, uiwebview, tvos

Obviously Xamarin UIWebView is officially not available for *tvOS*.
Some developers were able, however, to enable the WebView control on *tvOS* by editing the file [`Availability.h`](https://github.com/steventroughtonsmith/tvOSBrowser).

Is it technically possible to use the same approach within Xamarin on some kind of `UIWebView.h`?

If yes, where is it located in the source tree?

I would like to use the object `UIWebView` in a Xamarin *tvOS* project, which is prohibited by Apple. There is already a detailed discussion on how to implement a workaround in Objective-C, but I would like to implement a similar workarround in Xamarin C# like [in this SO question: "Web app in tvOS"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32503582/web-app-in-tvos).

How can I do that?

Comment: Could you be more specific about what you what you want to archieve and add some sample eventually?

Comment: the use of WebView is prohibited by Apple in tvOS Apps

A workarround in Objective C is introduced in this thread

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32503582/web-app-in-tvos?noredirect=1&lq=1

I would like to do the same using C# Xamarin iOS