# Xamarin tvOS WebView

Tags: xamarin, webview, tvos

I found this topic [Web app in tvOS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32503582/web-app-in-tvos)
in which a workaround to use WebView in tvOS is:

```
let webViewClass : AnyObject.Type = NSClassFromString("UIWebView")!
let webViewObject : NSObject.Type = webViewClass as! NSObject.Type
let webview: AnyObject = webViewObject.init()
let url = NSURL(string: "https://www.google.com")
let request = NSURLRequest(URL: url!)
webview.loadRequest(request)
```

However, I am using Xamarin to develop my tvOS app. How can I translate that Swift code to Xamarin C#?

Comment: You can use the Xamarin.iOS ObjCRuntime to obtain the ObjC class and alloc/init it... but you can not use that UIWebView in an tvOS app in the Apple Store.

Comment: Hety,did you solve the issue?I can ahsre my code if you want.

Comment: Not yet, please share your code in an answer.