# How to open URL in tvOS simulator?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, swiftui, tvos

is there any way how to openURL in Xcode tvOS simulator (latest version) as there is no Safari installed on default?

The issue my Button returns now is following:

> [default] Failed to open URL http://yoururl.com: Error
>   Domain=FBSOpenApplicationServiceErrorDomain Code=1 "The request to
>   open "com.apple.PBLinkHandler" failed."
>   UserInfo={BSErrorCodeDescription=RequestDenied,
>   NSUnderlyingError=0x6000037458c0 {Error
>   Domain=FBSOpenApplicationErrorDomain Code=4 "Unable to open
>   application for the given URL. If this is a universal link ensure a
>   supported target app is installed."
>   UserInfo={BSErrorCodeDescription=NotFound,
>   NSLocalizedFailureReason=Unable to open application for the given URL.
>   If this is a universal link ensure a supported target app is
>   installed.}}, NSLocalizedDescription=The request to open
>   "com.apple.PBLinkHandler" failed., FBSOpenApplicationRequestID=0xec14,
>   NSLocalizedFailureReason=The request was denied by service delegate
>   (PBProcessManager) for reason: NotFound ("Unable to open application
>   for the given URL. If this is a universal link ensure a supported
>   target app is installed").}

Thanks in advance

Comment: Maybe checkout this answer about displaying web contents on tvOS: https://stackoverflow.com/a/32715013/6426085